# How to use ListenerHandle in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, changelistener

I read [this article on ListenerHandles](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/01/dont-remove-listeners-use-listenerhandles.html), but I couldn't understand how to implement it in my code. I have a `ChangeListener` which I assign to my `CheckBoxes`. I need to change value of `CheckBoxes` without `Listeners` noticing it.

My code for creating `CheckBoxes`:

```
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.setText("CheckBox "+(i+1));
    checkBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(checkBoxListener(checkBox));

    myVBox.getChildren().add(checkBox);
    }
```

`ChangeListener` code:

```
private ChangeListener<Boolean> checkBoxListener(CheckBox checkBox) {
        return new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean selected) {
                if (selected) {
                    System.out.println("CheckBox got selected");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("CheckBox got deselected");
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Code that needs to get done without `Listener` noticing:

```
public void deselectCheckBoxes(){
      for(Node node : myVBox.getChildren()){
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) node;
            System.out.println("Removing listener");
            checkBox.selectedProperty().removeListener(checkBoxListener(checkBox));

            checkBox.setSelected(false);

            System.out.println("Adding listener back");
            checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(checkBoxListener(checkBox));
       }
}
```

`Listener` still noticing that I'm deselecting `CheckBox` through this function. Can someone explain how I could implement `ListenerHandle` way in my code?

Thank you very much for your answer. I adjusted `ChangeListener`, so that I can get object from my `CheckBox`:

```
ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
            if (isNowSelected) {
                BooleanProperty booleanProperty = (BooleanProperty) obs;
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)booleanProperty.getBean();

                System.out.println("Selected: "+(Bank)checkBox.getUserData());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not selected");
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few notes:

1. Your code doesn't work, because your `checkBoxListener()` creates a different listener every time you invoke it. So the listener you attempt to remove is not the listener you initially added, and so the call to `removeListener(...)` does nothing. Worse, you add a *different* listener later when you try to restore the original. Consequently, you should find that checking the check box after the `deselectCheckBoxes()` method has been called invokes the listener multiple times.
2. To me, needing to do this at all is usually the sign of a poor design. You really shouldn't care *how* the check box is deselected (i.e. programmatically or by the user). The controller should really be invoking methods on the model so that the model is in sync with the state of the UI. From this perspective, the cause of the check box becoming deselected should not matter.
3. Note that this functionality is implemented "out of the box" by Tomas Mikula's [ReactFX framework](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX). (Basically you can subscribe to "event streams", which can include streams of changes to properties. You can make those streams "suspendible" and suspend them during specific operations.)

Anyway, assuming you really need this for some reason, as I understand it, the intention is that you would do something like this:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

public class ListenerHandle<T>  {

    private final ObservableValue<T> observable ;
    private final ChangeListener<? super T> listener ;

    private boolean attached ;

    public ListenerHandle(ObservableValue<T> observable, ChangeListener<? super T> listener) {
        this.observable = observable ;
        this.listener = listener ;
    }

    public void attach() {
        if (! attached) {
            observable.addListener(listener);
            attached = true ;
        }
    }

    public void detach() {
        if (attached) {
            observable.removeListener(listener);
            attached = false ;
        }
    }


}
```

Then you can use this as

```
    ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
        if (isNowSelected) {
            System.out.println("Selected");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not selected");
        }

    };

    ListenerHandle<Boolean> handle = new ListenerHandle<>(checkBox.selectedProperty(), listener);
    handle.attach();
```

and to "turn off" handling, you would do

```
// ignore this change:
handle.detach();
checkBox.setSelected(false);
handle.attach();
```

Note that to make this work, you still need to keep a reference to the handle (you just no longer necessarily need to keep a separate reference to the property or node, and keep them "connected"). In your case, since you have multiple check boxes, since you have multiple check boxes and multiple listeners, you would need something like:

```
private List<ListenerHandle<Boolean>> checkBoxListenerHandles = new ArraryList<>();

// ...

ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
    if (isNowSelected) {
        System.out.println("CheckBox got selected");
    } else {
        System.out.println("CheckBox got deselected");
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.setText("CheckBox "+(i+1));
    checkBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    ListenerHandle<Boolean> handle = new ListenerHandle<>(checkBox.selectedProperty(), listener);
    handle.attach();
    checkBoxListenerHandles.add(handle);

    myVBox.getChildren().add(checkBox);
}
```

and then

```
public void deselectCheckBoxes(){

   checkBoxListenerHandles.forEach(ListenerHandle::detach);

   for(Node node : myVBox.getChildren()){
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) node;
        checkBox.setSelected(false);
   }

   checkBoxListenerHandles.forEach(ListenerHandle::attach);

}
```

Note that if you wanted to deselect (and ignore) a specific check box, you would have to know which handle belonged to that particular check box. You could do that with a `Map`, or similar, but at that point you have pretty much gained nothing compared to simply keeping references to the listeners and removing them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm currently learning which way would be best to handle listeners. I needed to pass `CheckBox` object to listener, basically I need to access object that is connected to `CheckBox` inside listener like `checkBox.getUserData()`. Can I do something like that? Sorry if it sounds a bit over complicated.